# Windows service status "Starting"

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have written a windows service which starts automatically and status becomes "started". Sometimes service status goes to "starting" state and impossible to recover to "started" state even after restarting the system. It might be happening because of some unhandled exception in the code.

```
public partial class EngineHostService : ServiceBase
{
    internal static ServiceHost _serviceHost = null;

    public EngineHostService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_serviceHost != null)
                _serviceHost.Close();

            _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(EngineService.Engine));
            _serviceHost.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandler.LogEvent(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (_serviceHost != null)
        {
            _serviceHost.Close();
            _serviceHost = null;
        }
    }

}
```

In the above code when constructor of Engine class executes, it throws some exception. 
I want to stop the service: 1- If some exception is thrown. 2- If any function I have called inside the constructor returns false.
Is there any way to stop the service as I want. If I would do so, I am sure to have service status either as "started" or "stopped". Suggest some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate concerns.
You should return from OnStart as quick as possible, so I'd suggest to spin up an asynchronous TPL task in your OnStart method and do nothing more.

In the asynchronous task you can do whatever you want.

By doing this your service would be able to complete OnStart and to move from Starting to Started properly.

Comment: "In the asynchronous task you can do whatever you want.

By doing this your service would be able to complete OnStart and to move from Starting to Started properly." It is allright...
But I want to stop the service from that asynchronous thread if some function return false or if there is any exception (handled or unhandled) thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either `InitializeComponent` is doing too much work, or that `EngineService.Engine` is doing much in *it's* startup. Frankly, you should be doing very little directly at startup: validating configuration and then just starting a worker thread (or a few) for the real work.

Answer (score 0):

The Service Control Manager expects OnStart to complete within 30 seconds.
If you startup requires more time, notify the SCM via RequestAdditionalTime(60 * 1000);
If OnStart takes too long SCM will alert 'Unable To Start Service'.
When OnStart completes your service MUST be ready to accept service requests.

Caution: 
Do not use the constructor to perform processing that should be in OnStart. Use OnStart to handle all initialization of your service. The constructor is called when the application's executable runs, not when the service runs.